# How to measure the average time spend monthly by an user on a Stack Exchange website?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I am looking for way to measure the average **engagement** of users on various Stack Exchange websites and across time and probably the time spend on the site is the best way to measure the engagement.

How can I get this information or something close to it?

Comment: This question has already been answered. 24 7 365. (We take leap days off.)

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Maybe *you* do!

Comment: One question: Why?  I don't want my bosses to know how much time I spend here =)

Comment: You all have too much spare time :) ... this is not for measuring the time of a specific user, is just for measuring the average time spent by all the users for a period of time.

Answer (score 5):

"time spent" is not a metric available to us mortals, maybe (well, *hopefully*!) not even to the devs. I guess the best you can do from the data dumps is to extract

- The frequency of answers
- The frequency of comments
- The frequency of edits

and interpolate some sort of activity index from them. Of course that is very hazy, because you'll have to guess how long a user needs on average to write an answer, for example ... Links could increase that time (because presumably, the user needs to copy&paste them from somewhere); edits over a short time span could drive the index up as well.

It's not much, but I think it's the best you can hope to achieve with the data available.

Comment: The answer is going to be "too much" anyway.